# How do i check if there is an Airplay device connected

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes, osx-mavericks

I'm wanting to do a script that needs to check if there is an airplay device connected and being used.
I have tried searching in many places but i can't seem to find any documentation on this, does anyone have any idea how i would do this?
To further clarify, I want a script that is something along the lines of:

```
 if airplay device is in use then //(pause for longer)
 else //(the script that is already there)
```

this is the current code i have

```
global okflag
set okflag to false
set front_app to (path to frontmost application as Unicode text)

-- check if iTunes is running 
tell application "System Events"
    if process "iTunes" exists then
        set okflag to true --iTunes is running
    end if
end tell

if okflag is true then
    set CV to output volume of (get volume settings)

tell application "iTunes"
    if (player state is playing) then
        set currentVolume to the sound volume
        set Timer to ""
        display dialog "Sleep Time (Minutes)" with title "iTunes Timer" default answer Timer buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2
        set Timer to text returned of the result
        set the_button to button returned of (display dialog "Shutdown after countdown?" with title "iTunes Timer" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button 2)
        delay Timer * 60
        repeat with i from currentVolume to 0 by -1
            set the sound volume to i
            delay 0.6
        end repeat
        pause
        set player position to (player position - 60)
        --Restore original volume
        set the sound volume to currentVolume
        if the_button is "Yes" then tell application "System Events"
            shut down
        end tell
    else
        display dialog "Nothing Playing" with title "iTunes Timer" giving up after 2
    end if


end tell

else
display dialog "iTunes is not running" with title "iTunes Timer" giving up after 2

end if
```

edit: added application for clarification of what i needed to find out

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.

But did not workout how to get a status if you are streaming say from iTunes. (so far)

But did workout that if airplay is being used as a Extended desktop space or Mirroring then That is picked up in the System Profile for displays. ***SPDisplaysDataType***

This applescript accounts for that at least.

```
      set connected to ""
try
    set connected to do shell script "system_profiler  SPDisplaysDataType | grep -i \"AirPlay\" "
    if connected contains "Connection Type: AirPlay" then
        set connected to "Connected as a Display or mirroring"
    end if
on error err
    log err
    if err contains "The command exited with a non-zero status" then
        --do somthing
        set connected to "Not connected as a Display or mirroring"
    end if
end try
connected
```

---

**UPDATE***

The iTunes commands now have some airplay commands. Not sure when they appeared.
But one example of use:

```
    tell application "iTunes"
        set isPlaying to player state


    if isPlaying is playing then
            log isPlaying
            set airPlayEnabled to AirPlay enabled
            if airPlayEnabled then

                  log airPlayEnabled

            else

                airPlayEnabled
    end if


        else

            log isPlaying
        end if

    end tell
```

The **AirPlay enabled**  AFAIK only for the iTunes player it is run against. And not for any other device that may be occupying the Airplay device

Comment: Thanks for this, although it's not what i was looking for, I probably didn't word it properly, I should probably explain what i have so far, when I hit a particular key, it runs a program which fades the sound on iTunes out, and then back in again and starts playing again, what i want it to do is have a greater delay fading in when connected to airplay because there is always a connection delay that negates the fade in.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add this information and any other that helps explain what you want. Including said app.